# Expected a value of type (String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>, but got one of type(dynamic) => Builder

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to to call HTTP API to show the information of products on the Carousel Slider but it gets the error:

```
    The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown building FutureBuilder<void>(dirty, state:
    _FutureBuilderState<void>#bd897):
    Expected a value of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>', but got one of type
    '(dynamic) => Builder'
    The relevant error-causing widget was: FutureBuilder<void>
```

Could anyone help me to solve it, many thanks!

```
            class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
              final List<String> items;
              const HomePage({
                Key? key,
                required this.items,
              }) : super(key: key);
            
              @override
              State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
            }
            
            class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
              int activeIndex = 0;
              setActiveDot(index) {
                setState(() {
                  activeIndex = index;
                });
              }
            var data;
      Future<void> getData() async {
        final response = await http
            .get(Uri.parse('https://berequirement.herokuapp.com/products'));
    
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          data = jsonDecode(response.body);
        } else {}
      }
              List<Information> postList = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
                  body: Column(children: [Expanded(
                      child: FutureBuilder(
                          future: getData(),
                          builder: (context, snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                              return const Center(child: Text('Loading ...'));
                            } else {
                              return Stack(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 500,
                                    width: 400,
                                   // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                    child: CarouselSlider(
                                      options: CarouselOptions(
                                        autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
                                        autoPlayAnimationDuration:
                                            const Duration(seconds: 1),
                                        viewportFraction: 1.0,
                                        onPageChanged: (index, ActiveDot) {
                                          setActiveDot(index);
                                        },
                                      ),
                                      items: data.map((item) {
                                        return Builder(
                                          builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                            return Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        data['data'][item]['name'],
                                        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          fontSize: 22,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      const SizedBox(height: 10),
                                      Text(
                                        "Item No . ${data['data'][item]['code']}",
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                            // fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: 12,
                                            color: Colors.grey),
                                      ),
                                      const SizedBox(height: 5),
                                      Text(
                                        "Item Type . ${data['data'][item]['type']}",
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                            // fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: 13,
                                            color: Colors.black),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        ("\$ ${data['data'][item]['price']}"),
                                        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                          textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              color: Colors.black,
                                              fontSize: 22),
                                        ),
                                      ),
            
                                    ],
                                  );
                                          },
                                        );
                                      }).toList(),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Positioned(
                                    left: 0,
                                    right: 0,
                                    bottom: 10,
                                    child: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                        children: List.generate(data.length, (idx) {
                                          return activeIndex == idx
                                              ? const ActiveDot()
                                              : const InactiveDot();
                                        }
        )
        ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              );
            
                             
                            }
                          }),
                    ),
            
            ])}
```

Comment: Can we see the getData() method as well? Also, a good practice would be obtaining a future before the build method and using it for the `FutureBuilder`.

For example using a `late Future _getData` and assigning it the `getData()` function during `initState()`.

Comment: I updated the getData(), could you check it and help me, many thanks bro !

Answer (score 1):

Looked a bit through the updated post and noticed the `Future<void>` return value of `getData()`:

```
Future<void> getData() async {
        final response = await http
            .get(Uri.parse('https://berequirement.herokuapp.com/products'));
    
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          data = jsonDecode(response.body);
        } else {}
      }
```

To be able to use this in a FutureBuilder, I recommend that you return a value at the end of the funtion. For example:

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getData() async {
        final response = await http
            .get(Uri.parse('https://berequirement.herokuapp.com/products'));
    
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          var thisData = jsonDecode(response.body);
          return thisData;
        } else {
          return {};
        }
      }
```

And as such, modify the `data` in your `FutureBuilder` with `snapshot.data`.

EDIT: You can read more about `FutureBuilders` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).

EDIT2: Looked more through your code and encountered this:

```
...
data.map((item) {
    return Builder(
        builder: (BuildContext context)
...
```

There is no need for the `Builder()` widget. You can return the `Column()`. This should explain your error:

```dart
Expected a value of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>', but got one of type
    '(dynamic) => Builder'
```

Comment: I fixed code following your help but it thrown this erorr: The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<Map<String, dynamic>>(dirty,
state: _FutureBuilderState<Map<String, dynamic>>#c5b97):
'map'
Dynamic call of null.
Receiver: null
Arguments: [Instance of '(dynamic) => Column']

Comment: Could you help me: Expected a value of type (String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>, but got one of type(dynamic) => Column

Comment: Looked through the `carousel_slider` package and noticed there was a `.builder()` method. Try using that instead of mapping the List, by passing to the `itemCount` param the snapshot.data.length, and then you'll have the builder function param as well, which might allow you to access the index of the built item.